# How to add dependency to Cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying to create a Cocoapods library. My library will include Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK as dependency. I used following commands

```
pod lib create BannerViewController
 > my email address
What language do you want to use?? [ ObjC / Swift ]
 > Swift
Would you like to include a demo application with your library? [ Yes / No ]
 > Yes
Which testing frameworks will you use? [ Quick / None ]
 > None
Would you like to do view based testing? [ Yes / No ]
 > No
```

I then edited BannerViewController.podspec added following line

```
s.dependency 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.0'
```

I tried to use `pod lib lint BannerViewController.podspec`

```
[!] BannerViewController did not pass validation, due to 1 error and 3 warnings.
You can use the `--no-clean` option to inspect any issue.
```

I tried to pod update in Example directory and got following error

```
[!] The 'Pods-BannerViewController_Example' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/Developer/BannerViewController/Example/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-7.4.0/GoogleMobileAds.framework)
```

I don't know how can I add Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK to my development pod so that I can test my code locally. Cocoapods documentation is not clear. I am using Cocoapods 0.38.2

Answer (score 0):

Use `pod lib lint BannerViewController.podspec --use-libraries`